# How to unlock columns in pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin, unlock

I want to unlock the columns which appearing in the following pic:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F7cb.png

I know that the answer is make id a primary key. but the problem here is that I can't make id a primary key because there are two rows empty in id column and I can't delete these  rows because the column locked!
Please try to help me.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

You cannot update or delete rows if you don't have primary key. That is the reason they're locked. It's impossible to identify rows uniquely for update/delete queries to run.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when we have not turn on the primary key on our column of any which we want to make primary key . just go to the properties of the table and turn on the primary key of your column which you want to make primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above correct answers, if in your query you can include the primary key , for example id , then the result set won't have locked data.

```
select id, name, username from users where username = 'abc';
```

insted of `select name, username from users where username = 'abc';` which locks the result set.